# How to remove Parallax effect on window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically what I want to do is when the screen is resized to the width of a tablet/mobile device I want the parallax effect removed from the background. [This website](http://andon.studio-themes.com/html_rev/) has the effect I'm looking for but I don't know how it is achieved.

I'm using the same jquery parallax script (http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/) as the website that I linked so technically I should be able to achieve the same result.

edit: I managed to fix it myself. Here's the code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #l-HeaderContainer{
        background-attachment: scroll !important;
        background-position: center !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: If we post your current Javascript/jQuery code, along with your HTML and CSS, we can take a look and help you out.

Comment: @AndyM All it is is a div using the jquery parallax plugin I linked in my original comment with the css of:

`#l-HeaderContainer{
 background: url(../img/thief.png) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed #000507;
}`

I tried this but it didn't work:

`@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 #l-HeaderContainer{
  background: url(../img/thief.png) 50% 0 no-repeat scroll #000507;
 }
}

`

Comment: Can you add the javascript code to your original answer as well? You'll probably need to listen for a window re-size event and then remove the parallax listeners, but without seeing how you're adding parallax, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

Your css won't work since it is strict with ids.

Ids should start with an alphabet. Change your id to something like `HeadContainer1` and do this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #HeaderContainer1{
        background-attachment: scroll !important;
        background-position: center !important;
    }
}
```

[SOURCE](http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/)

Comment: It's a "L" not a "one", sorry for the confusion.